# Computing a Fibonacci sequence in Terraform

Tags: terraform, fibonacci

The title is really all there is to the question: how would you compute the values of a Fibonacci sequence (first N values, where N is an input variable) and store them in a Terraform `local` variable?

This could, of course, be done with an `external` data source, but I'm looking for a way to do it in pure Terraform.

There's no real need to actually do this, but the Fibonacci sequence is a representation of a problem I need to solve in Terraform (where values in a list depend on previous values of that same list).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to create your own [external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) for that, as in TF you can't access existing list elements during iteration when you create the lists itself.

And specific to Fibonacci sequence. I would just per-compute its values, and then just read any number of values I need from a list in TF or a file. Usually you would know a possible maximum number of those elements your app requires. Thus there is no reason to recalculate it every single time.

Comment: Yeah, I could always use an external data source, but I'm trying to do it in a way that doesn't use any external calls.